# TensorExpand ignores assumptions?

Tags: assumptions, tensors

Here's a minimal example to demonstrate my problem:

```
TensorWedge[e[i_], e[i_]] ^= 0;
TensorExpand[TensorWedge[3*e[1], 4*e[1]]]
TensorExpand[TensorWedge[x*e[1], y*e[1]]]
Assuming[Element[(x|y), Reals], 
 TensorExpand[TensorWedge[x*e[1], y*e[1]]]]
```

I get zero as result for the first and third tensor expansion, but not for the second.  This works as expected.  But now:

```
Assuming[Element[Indexed[da,{_,_}], Reals],
 TensorExpand[
  TensorWedge[Indexed[da,{1,2}]*e[1], Indexed[da,{2,3}]*e[1]]]]
```

I expected zero here as well, but that's not what I get.  The pattern is obviously right as the difference between the following two expressions demonstrates:

```
Simplify[Sqrt[Indexed[da,{2,3}]^2]]
Assuming[Element[Indexed[da,{_,_}], Reals], 
 Simplify[Sqrt[Indexed[da,{2,3}]^2]]]
```

So, what's the problem with `TensorExpand` that I'm missing?

Comment: Use Element[(Indexed[da, {1, 2}] | Indexed[da, {2, 3}]), Reals] instead of Element[Indexed[da,{_,_}], Reals]. TensorExpand is not yet able to infer information from patterned Element assumptions.

Comment: @jose Thanks, that works for me, although it's a bit clumsy.  If you make this an answer, I'll accept it.  (I'm suprised to learn that different functions in Mathematica use assumptions in different ways.)